# Unable to perform git pull "Connection to gitlab.com closed by remote host."

Tags: git, gitlab

I have recently started getting an error as below 
Connection to gitlab.com closed by remote host.
fatal: The remote end hung up unexpectedly

I am able to push and pull code to my repository on gitlab successfully form my local machine but I cannot perform a pull from the server. 
Can anyone please help to guide me on what I should do?

Thank you.